# Using dependencies in wp_register_style() for wordpress

Tags: function, styles, wordpress

I am trying to get a custom css file to load after the plugin stylesheets. I was thinking I could use the `$deps` parameter of `wp_register_style()`, but the css file does not load at all when I add the array(). This happens no matter what is included in the `$deps` array(), ie (array('style')
, array('style.css')).

Is there an issue with the call, or a better way of doing this?

**In my functions.php**

```
// Load custom css
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'prefix_add_my_stylesheet');

function prefix_add_my_stylesheet() {
    wp_register_style( 'custom-supersized-styles', get_template_directory_uri(). '/css/custom-supersized-styles.css', array('style','supersized');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-supersized-styles' );
}
```

Comment: When you say "the page breaks" do you get any specific error messages?  (Sometimes you need to [enable debug mode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) to see specific errors).

Comment: Updated the post. The page does not break, but the css file I have enqueued does not load at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the [WP Supersized](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-supersized/) plugin try registering your function like so:

```
// Load custom css
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'prefix_add_my_stylesheet', 999);
```

The dependencies array (the parameter you're attempting to use to add `supersized` with) depends on `supersized` having *already* been registered by WordPress.  If you set the priority of your own `prefix_add_my_stylesheet` to a higher number, it *should* then load *after* the plugin has registered and loaded its CSS (and thus will be available).

In addition, you can remove the `style` as a dependency.  (`style` is never registered by WordPress as a dependency handler, and your enqueued scripts / css should be loading after style.css loads anyway).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Adding priority to the action still loads the plugin stylesheet after the custom style sheet, overriding the styles I am trying to change.

Comment: @CareyEstes Interesting... I just installed this plugin on a plain vanilla WP installation with the 2012 theme, created my own "extra" css file to be loaded after the plugin's css, and it loaded after just fine.  I would search your theme code maybe for any other instances of `wp_enqueue_scripts` and `wp_enqueue_styles` to be sure nothing else is playing into the mix.  Maybe another definition for loading styles is overriding your code here somewhere?

Comment: I cleared out the functions.php except for the single enqueue_script action. Still no luck.

Comment: I had a syntax error. Missing closing parenthesis for register_style